# JSONObject Array returns null for some of the data in android

Tags: android, arrays, json, android-volley, getjson

I'm getting problems with JSON to Android.  For some reason some of the data when i receive it using JSONObject.getInt method it returns some of the data null.  Not all the data i receive returns null it seems like only the Data type that returns null is Integers and i have other Integer data and they receive it just fine without it ever being null. It seems to be consistent with only 3 of the integer variables. I've read this as it being being a bug somewhere but I don't know for sure if thats the case.  By the way i'm using Android Volley.

Is there a better way for this?

```
        StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            AppConfig.URL_LOGIN, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Login Response: " + response.toString());
            hideDialog();

            try {
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");

                // Check for error node in json
                if (!error) {
                    // user successfully logged in
                    // Create login session
                    session.setLogin(true);

                    String uid = jObj.getString("uid");

                    JSONObject user = jObj.getJSONObject("user");


                    ...(OTHER Variables that return fine)


                    int activitylvl = user.getInt("activitylvl");//get null
                    int meal_plan = user.getInt("meal_plan");//get null
                    int workout_plan = user.getInt("workout_plan");//get null


        Continues.....};
```

EDITS:
Heres my result to my response

```
{
  "error": false,
  "uid": "56551efd883b55.31836995",
  "user": {
    "name": "Test",
    "email": "test@gmail.com",
    "goal": "1",
    "image": "",
    "gender": "M",
    "birthdate": "8/6/1993",
    "height_cm": "182",
    "height_ft": "6",
    "height_in": "0",
    "weight_kg": "74",
    "weight_lbs": "165",
    "activitylvl": null,
    "calories": "2861.43",
    "meal_plan": null,
    "workout_plan": null,
    "adjust_calories_wd": "0",
    "adjust_calories_nwd": "0",
    "workout_week": "false, false, false, false, false, false, false",
    "created_at": "2015-11-24 21:37:49",
    "updated_at": "2015-11-24 21:37:49"
  }
}
```

PHP

```
 // get the user by email and password
$user = $db->getUserByEmailAndPassword($email, $password);

if ($user != false) {
    // use is found
    $response["error"] = FALSE;
    $response["uid"] = $user["unique_id"];
    $response["user"]["name"] = $user["name"];
    $response["user"]["email"] = $user["email"];
    $response["user"]["goal"] = $user["goal"];
    $response["user"]["image"] = $user["image"];
    $response["user"]["gender"] = $user["gender"];
    $response["user"]["birthdate"] = $user["birthdate"];
    $response["user"]["height_cm"] = $user["height_cm"];
    $response["user"]["height_ft"] = $user["height_ft"];
    $response["user"]["height_in"] = $user["height_in"];
    $response["user"]["weight_kg"] = $user["weight_kg"];
    $response["user"]["weight_lbs"] = $user["weight_lbs"];
    $response["user"]["activitylvl"] = $user["activitylvl"];
    $response["user"]["calories"] = $user["calories"];
    $response["user"]["meal_plan"] = $user["meal_plan"];
    $response["user"]["workout_plan"] = $user["workout_plan"];
    $response["user"]["adjust_calories_wd"] = $user["adjust_calories_wd"];
    $response["user"]["adjust_calories_nwd"] = $user["adjust_calories_nwd"];
    $response["user"]["workout_week"] = $user["workout_week"];
    $response["user"]["created_at"] = $user["created_at"];
    $response["user"]["updated_at"] = $user["updated_at"];
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    // user is not found with the credentials
    $response["error"] = TRUE;
    $response["error_msg"] = "Login credentials are wrong. Please try again!";
    echo json_encode($response);
}

public function getUserByEmailAndPassword($email, $password) {
    //DO this for users db as well
    $result = mysqli_query($this->conn,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email'") or die(mysqli_connect_errno());

    // check for result
    $no_of_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if ($no_of_rows > 0) {
        $result = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        $salt = $result['salt'];
        $encrypted_password = $result['encrypted_password'];
        $hash = $this->checkhashSSHA($salt, $password);

        // check for password
        if ($encrypted_password == $hash) {
            return $result;
        }

    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: integer (int) could not be null its has some value or it hold zero. post your response structure.

Comment: Edit  your question, use another applicatiion to fetch the json and post it on the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out the problem was with the user response name it was a php problem:

> inside the function of getUserByEmailAndPassword  there is a method
>   called
>
> mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query);
>
> this grabs the column name and sets it in an array with the key name as the column name in mysql database I had the wrong name.

INCORRECT

$response["user"]["activitylvl"] = $user["activitylvl"];

$response["user"]["meal_plan"] = $user["meal_plan"];

$response["user"]["workout_plan"] = $user["workout_plan"];

CORRECT

$response["user"]["activitylvl"] = $user["activity"];

$response["user"]["meal_plan"] = $user["mealplan"];

$response["user"]["workout_plan"] = $user["workoutplan"];

Answer (score 0):

If you are certain that the data is not null in your response but it is getting null when your are trying to parse it, and you are also sure that the data field name is correct, you can do the following as an alternative solution:

```
if (user.getString("activitylvl") != null && !user.getString("activitylvl").equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
    int activitylvl = Integer.parseInt(user.getString("activitylvl"));
}
```

Which gets the `JSON` field as a string object then converts it to an integer object.